# Cloud Functions for Firebase secure calls from android app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

How can I make a call to a Cloud Function from and android app such that the server knows that the calling app is an authenticated user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about an HTTPS type function, you can have the client pass an authentication token in the request to identify the end user that's already been authenticated by Firebase Authentication.  The function can then use the admin SDK to validate that user and take actions based on their request.

You can see sample code from the Firebase team [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api).